# De-obfuscate a picture with statistical information?

Tags: ocr, dsp

I need to get this kind of information into numbers, how?

[image]

[image]

**Perhaps related**

1. https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1054/how-do-i-recover-the-signal-from-an-ecg-image
2. https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1080/find-a-specific-line-in-a-picture
3. R's biOps [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/biOps/index.html) as a generic tool. R's PET has Hough transform [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PET/PET.pdf) (but may not work in this domain but HT does not seem too complicated, [here](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough-Transformation))

Answer (score 1):

[There's the Haskell `explore` package meant to do that:](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/explore)

> Very first prototype of a command line tool to **extract pixel positions matching a given colour to help reconstruct plot data**.

(Also see [its homepage](http://corsis.sourceforge.net/index.php/Haskell/Explore).  I've never used this, though.)